# Connect refused: error about connect() function

Tags: c, http, tcp

I want to enter the IP address in argv[1] and connect with socket s. 
But it show connect refused when I compile this and enter the ./client [IP address]
[IP address] mean like this 192.168.0.1
Terminal's result is this.

IP : 192.168.0.1
connect: Connection refused

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int s, client_s;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int addr_len;
    int len;
    int read_len;
    char msg[1000];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error : Use IP address\n");
        return 1; 
    }

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(s == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 0;
    }
    server_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_aton(argv[1] , &server_addr.sin_addr);
    memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    printf("IP : %s\n", inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr));

    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        close(s);
        return 0;
    }

    char Header_line[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    char Host_header[] = "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n";
    char Connection_header[] = "Connection: close\r\n";
    char crlf[] = "\r\n";
    strcat(Header_line, Host_header);
    strcat(Header_line, Connection_header);
    strcat(Header_line, crlf);

   len = send(s, &Header_line, strlen(Header_line), 0);
    if(len == -1)
    {
        //perror("Write");
        close(s);
        return 0;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        read_len = recv(s, msg, 1000, 0);
        if(read_len == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            close(s);
            return 0;
        }
        if(read_len == 0)
        {
            printf("Disconnected!\n");
            break;
        }
        write(1, msg, read_len);
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

How can solve the problem about the connect() error?

Comment: Are you sure there is a server listening at 192.168.0.1:80? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: No, 192.168,0.1:80 is just example IP. I want listening about 125.209.222.141.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information.** I rephrase my question: Are you sure there is a server listening at the address you specify as command line argument? Did you type the correct address? Can you use a web browser on the same system to connect to this address? Are there any firewalls or proxies involved? Try to connect using `nc` or `telnet`, e.g. `telnet 125.209.222.141 80`. If you type something and press CR/Enter you should get some (error) response. For me, your program works. It prints an HTTP response when I call it with argument 125.209.222.141

Comment: `strcat(Header_line, Host_header);` You should not write beyond the end of a char array.